# jQuery Textillate options not creating the expected result

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-textillate

I have this textillate options set, already tried some examples on the web but no animation is running, on what I think is the correct.
The objective is to create a button where the first text element goes fadeOutUp letter by letter randomly, and the second text goes fadeInUp randomly as well, this is what I'v tried:

```
        var textilateoptions = {
            autoStart: true,
            // in animation settings
            in: {
                // set the effect name
                effect: 'fadeInUp',
                // set the delay factor applied to each consecutive character
                delayScale: 20,
                delay: 50,
                sync: true,
                shuffle: true,
                reverse: false,
            },
            // out animation settings.
            out: {
                effect: 'fadeOutUp',
                delayScale: 20,
                delay: 50,
                sync: true,
                shuffle: true,
                reverse: false,
            },
            // set the type of token to animate (available types: 'char' and 'word')
            type: 'char'
        };
        
        $('.btneffect .infobtn').textillate(textilateoptions);
        textilateoptions.autoStart = false;
        $('.btneffect .infobtn2').textillate(textilateoptions);
        
        $('.btneffect').hover(function(){
            $(this).find(".infobtn").textillate('out');
            $(this).find(".infobtn2").textillate('in');
        },function(){
            $(this).find(".infobtn").textillate('in');
            $(this).find(".infobtn2").textillate('out');
        });
```

Codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/msmzuppa/pen/WNEobgv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct here

```
 // set to true to animate all the characters at the same time
    sync: false,
```

and version of animate.css

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css

change

use `3.7.2` instead of `4.1.1`

and

`sync: true`

to

`sync: false`

make it works

https://codepen.io/prajin-tst/pen/rNzYzwG

Comment: Well, that does letter by letter individually, but  I'm not seeing any animation tho

Comment: you must use animate version `3.7.2` instead of `4.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

Textillate's [github page](https://github.com/jschr/textillate) lists a few dependencies like `lettering.js` and `animate.css`. You might be missing the animate.css file as when I added the line `<link href="http://textillate.js.org/assets/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />` to your `Codepen`, I could get the text moving up on mouse over. Observed something similar in a test HTML page(included below) I created with your CSS, Javascript and HTML from Codepen.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://textillate.js.org/assets/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <style>
            .infobtn {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position: relative;
                bottom: 0;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                line-height: 1;
                color: #f00;
            }
            .btneffect .infobtn2 {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                color: #000;
            }
            .btneffect {
                border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="btneffect corpri1 letra14 bold">
            <div class="infobtn animate corpri1">Todos os produtos</div>
            <div class="infobtn2 animate preto">Todos os produtos</div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://github.com/downloads/davatron5000/Lettering.js/jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://textillate.js.org/jquery.textillate.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                var textilateoptions = {
                    autoStart: true,
                    // in animation settings
                    in: {
                        // set the effect name
                        effect: "fadeInUp",
                        // set the delay factor applied to each consecutive character
                        delayScale: 20,
                        delay: 50,
                        sync: true,
                        shuffle: true,
                        reverse: false,
                    },
                    // out animation settings.
                    out: {
                        effect: "fadeOutUp",
                        delayScale: 20,
                        delay: 50,
                        sync: true,
                        shuffle: true,
                        reverse: false,
                    },
                    // set the type of token to animate (available types: 'char' and 'word')
                    type: "char",
                };

                $(".btneffect .infobtn").textillate(textilateoptions);
                textilateoptions.autoStart = false;
                $(".btneffect .infobtn2").textillate(textilateoptions);

                $(".btneffect").hover(
                    function () {
                        $(this).find(".infobtn").textillate("out");
                        $(this).find(".infobtn2").textillate("in");
                    },
                    function () {
                        $(this).find(".infobtn").textillate("in");
                        $(this).find(".infobtn2").textillate("out");
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: its already there

Comment: yes, I'v included those files, its in the example.. as you can see..

Comment: @MiguelMachado your version is wrong. See the link its working https://codepen.io/prajin-tst/pen/rNzYzwG

Answer (score 0):

I'v made my own plugin, thanks anyway